# Quais são os pros e contras de utilizar jquery no desenvolvimento mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, apache-cordova, mobile

Estou iniciando no desenvolvimento hibrido utilizando o Cordova (com visual studio) e em minhas pesquisas sobre frameworks javascript, tenho encontrado muitas pessoas utilizando AngularJS, e me surpreendi pelo fato de não encontrar ninguém que usa e recomenda JQuery (não JQuery Mobile). Porque não usar ? existe um porque ?

Comment: Olá,
não sei dizer porque não viu nenhum APP mobile com jQuery mais eu já....
e bem usado mais existe vários outros que acaba dependendo do programador escolher qual acha mais fácil. estou usando agora o framework do Google (;D) http://materializecss.com/about.html eu recomendo usar o jQuery mobile para fazer app ou este acima.

Comment: Olá Felipe, realmente existem diversos apps que utilizam o jQuery, porem não como binding de dados, a minha pergunta tinha sido mau explicada, sanei minhas dúvidas sobre binding, e hoje estou utilizando angularJs para tal, porem, ainda utilizo jQuery, mesmo porque estou utilizando materialize css também, e fica impossível sem o mesmo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Esta página](http://speckyboy.com/2014/12/18/dos-donts-building-html5-hybrid-apps/) recomenda não usar jQuery por se tratar de uma biblioteca pesada, e mesmo as versões jQuery UI e jQuery Mobile apresentam performance ruim, sendo que jQuery Mobile em particular impõe muita rigidez.

[Esta página](http://apachecordova.blogspot.com.br/2012/11/who-is-murdering-phonegap-its-jquery.html) fornece alguns motivos pelos quais não se deve usar jQuery Mobile (que tem o jQuery como dependência) em aplicativos móveis, entre os quais ser pesado, pouco performático, mal documentado e ter muitos bugs, e segundo o site a razão é porque jQM é voltado para websites móveis e não aplicativos. Na seção de comentários alguns discordam dessa não-recomendação.

Lembro também de já ter lido algo sobre o jQuery tratar eventos de *click* e não de *touch*, que seria o mais adequado em aplicativos móveis. *Clicks* têm um delay de 300 milissegundos, o que prejudica muito a responsividade do aplicativo.